# Embedded kafka producer test

Tags: integration-testing, spring-kafka

I'm writing integration tests to test kafka producer.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {kafkaProducerConfig.class, KafkaProducerIT.InnerConfig.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaProducerInfo.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "...")
public class KafkaProducerIT {

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, "testtopic");

    @Autowired
    CustomKafkaProducer<String, String> KafkaProducer;

    @Autowired
    KafkaController kafkaController;

    @Test
    public void whenSendMessage_thenConsumeIt() throws InterruptedException {
        KafkaProducer.produceMessageToKafkaTopic("ahahahwow", "testtopic");
        kafkaController.countDownLatch.await();
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class InnerConfig {

        @Bean
        public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, Object> replyConsumerFactory) {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(replyConsumerFactory);
            factory.setBatchListener(true);
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        KafkaController kafkaController() {
            return new KafkaController();
        }

    }

    public static class KafkaController {

        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        @KafkaListener(topics = "testtopic")
        public void listen(final String payload) {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    }

}
```

Idea is that I want to send message to topic, read it using `KafkaController` and `CountDownLatch`. 
Issue that I have is that `CountDownLatch` is never triggered and test just hangs on `await`.

`CustomKafkaProducer` is just a wrapper which uses regular `kafkaTemplate` under the hood.

p.s.

During debug, there were several cases when flow entered listener and test passed. So issue is not related to wrong topic names etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set auto.offset.reset=earliest for the consumer. The default is latest so there is a race condition if the consumer starts after the record is sent.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong  - `auto.offset.reset=earliest` means that consumer will read all messages that were sent to topic from the beginning? Even if those messages were sent before consumer started?

Comment: That is correct. Since this is an embedded kafka, the only record will be the one sent in the test.